# Android studio always rebuilds application

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-2.1

I'm working on 2 applications.
One is a bootloader for another which is a main app.

They both have technically the same gradle settings (except package names).

The problem I have is that Android studio always rebuilds entire application for main, but for bootloader app, it just makes changes.

For example: 
When I press run on main application, these tasks gets executed (these tasks gets executed even if I don't edit anything):

```
Executing tasks: [:app:clean, :app:generateMesiDebugDebugSources, :app:generateMesiDebugDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:prepareMesiDebugDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:assembleDebugDebug]
```

While on bootloader app, these tasks gets executed:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:incrementalDebugSupportDex]
```

I'm sure I had changed something in my first app in settings but I can't figure out why. Each rebuild on main app takes about 2.5 min while executing small task on bootloader app takes about 2 seconds only, even if I make small changes (view changes, small activity changes).

I'm using Android Studio 2.1 (updated today), but these happens to me about 2-3 days ago.
My gradle version is 2.1.

Hope someone knows how to force Android studio to only compile and build changes in code, not entire app.

Thanks for answers.

Edit: Instant run command is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I think "Instant Run" setting is not enabled in your first application.

**Mac**
Go to Android Studio->Preferences->Build, Execution, Deployment->Instant Run->Select the Enable Instant Run check box

**Windows** Use the settings dialog and do the same procedure mentioned above

Comment: Actually, that was my first check. It is enabled. I'll update my question.